# Click Tab another way than by Selenium Webdriver SendKeys in Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I'm working on FF 56 and I can not use older version so I have problems with sendKeys function. In case of just sending values to element I did it by :

```
jsexec.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + value +"';", WebElement_LocatedBySelenium);
```

but now I need to click TAB or ENTER to reload fields in my form.

Any Ideas ?
Maybe there is some better way than JSexecutror

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little hard to understand. Do you mean you want to take focus away from the field so the "blur" event can trigger?

I do this by locating the body or container element and sending a click to that.

Comment: Yes, something like this. Best way would be by clicking TAB button but I will try with clicking on body of page.

Comment: Nope :( It has to be TAB. Does not work when I click on some random point on body.

Comment: What about  `WebElement_LocatedBySelenium.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);`  or 
 `new Actions(driver).sendKeys(WebElement_LocatedBySelenium, Keys.TAB).bui‌​ld().perform();`